# Are handlebar-mounted child seats illegal in Germany?

Tags: child-seat, germany

I was told that handlebar-mounted child seats such as the [Yepp Mini](http://www.yepp.nl/en/product/mini/) and the [Bobike Mini](https://bobike.com/product/detail/classic-mini) are illegal in Germany.

People say a lot of things about what is and what isn't legal while biking in Germany. Can anyone find me some kind of authoritative documentation on this?

Comment: Are you in Germany?  Do you see these seats in use at all?

Comment: Yes, and I can't say I've been looking until recently so I'm not sure.

Comment: What's strange is that front seats are fairly common in Germany, at least compared to the UK where they're much rarer than rear seats

Comment: Previous to living in Berlin I was in Amsterdam where front (handlebar mounted) bike seats are common.

Answer (score 7):

Front-mounted child seats are not illegal in Germany but face stronger restrictions than seats mounted in the back. Good sources and discussions (in German):

- http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stvo_2013/__21.html (the law)
- https://www.verkehrswacht-medien-service.de/kindersitze_fahrrad.html (good overview from a reliable source)

You need to consider in addition what kind of seats are adequate as covered by norms which provide the restrictions I alluded to:

- http://www.kinder-fahrrad-sitz.de/stvo-ece-r44-din-en14344-praktischerklaert/
- http://www.bike-eu.com/laws-regulations/artikel/2010/8/en-14344-european-standard-for-childs-seats-for-bicycles-1018845 (good explanation in English)

The [EN 14344](https://www.podilates.gr/sites/default/files/EN_14344.e.2004.pdf) norm is electronically available and covers every detail imaginable. It says in particular about front seats:

> *8.3 Additional requirements for front seats* Front seats shall have at least one attachment point to the cycle, which shall not be the
>   handlebar or the extension of the handlebar stem.

Comment: From the first link: "Weder Sitz noch Fußstützen dürfen an einem beweglichen Teil des Rads befestigt sein, etwa dem Lenker oder der Gabel. Ideal sind am Sattelrohr befestigte Sitze."

Which says a front-mounted seat isn't allowed to attach to any moving component like the handlebars or front forks, which specifically excludes the models I mention above.

Comment: No contradiction to what I said but thanks for the clarification. I would make sure that the seat I'm using conforms to the DIN EN 14344 norm.

Comment: Also from the Yepp FAQ (http://www.yepp.nl/en/support/faq/child-bike-seats/): "All Yepp bike seats comply with the strict European safety norm EN 14344". Which contradicts the above, because the Yepp mini attaches to the handlebar stem.

Comment: @RobertAtkins The second link is where you got the quote from and that's just some random website. They've absolutely no source for what they're writing there and I'm pretty sure that's also where the rumor about that 'front seats are illegal' sentiment comes from. The law says "[...] und durch Radverkleidungen oder gleich wirksame Vorrichtungen dafür gesorgt ist, dass die Füße der Kinder nicht in die Speichen geraten können. "

Which just means that what ever seat you use must prevent child's feets/legs from getting into the spokes. There is nothing about moveable parts or anything like it.